# How do i group products by categories in woocommerce rest api better?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on this e-commerce Android project and it’s supposed to display products and categories from a woocommerce site.
I am able to separately fetch the categories and products very well using the REST API But still having issues with filtering products by categories. In a way that say I have 3 categories `A, B, C`, I’d love to have products filtered under each of the categories.

This is what I have tried `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=15?&customer_key=ck_123&consumer_key=ck_456`
The above returns products under category of Id 15 but without a parent dictionary to show that it’s from say `category B`.

Then I also used `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=15,16,17?&customer_key=ck_123&consumer_key=ck_456` to return products under the 3 categories of Ids `15,16,17`

But the problem with this is that it ends up returning all the categories without grouping them by each category to which they belong. 
How do I change the above to  show a parent category outside of each of the corresponding products?

Question no. 2
Is there any way to fetch payments and products in the cart but still with the Woocommerce rest api ?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You Should try categories=15 instead of category=15

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?categories=15&?consumer_key=ck_6b20b87f3dd27c9a9e878a3d5baf03c47656a903&consumer_secret={{consumer_secret}}
```

As I am checking on my browser and postman, it's working fine,
See Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

If you want to check the path you should run URL(https://example.com/wp-json/) on your browser and get path/URL. see screenshot :

[image]